# Python - How to average user input value based on provided keys?

Tags: python

I am attempting to write a script that allow users to submit letter grades for baseball prospects and have those grades averaged based on what users submit.

1. User inputs grade for a prospect (B+ for prospect1)
2. All inputs are converted from lettergrades to numbergrades so they can be averaged.
3. Prospects are sorted by highest to lowest grades.
4. Grades are re-converted back to letter grades.

I believe I have step 2 covered but I am iffy on how to complete the rest of the code.

To simplify things, let's say we are given a list of 5 prospects. Users will grade each of them. As each additional user adds their input of grades, the average grade of each prospect should be updated and the order of their ranking simultaneously sorted.

```
prospects = ['prospect1', 'prospect2', 'prospect3', 'prospect4', 'prospect5']

grades = {'A+':98, 'A':95, 'A-':92, 'B+':88, 'B':85, 'B-':82, 'C+':78, 'C':75} #grading system where A+ = 98, A = 95 etc

def numbergrade(lettergrade):
    return grades[lettergrade] #function to convert lettergrade to numbergrade
```

How would you compile a list that would add an element every time there is a new user input and at the same time have the grade match the correct prospect? Should I be using a dictionary here?

Answer (score 0):

This will iterate through each prospect in the list, ask for a rating and add the rating to the dictionary 'out'. There is no validation of the user inputs so you would probably want to ensure that they've entered a value that is in your grades.

It becomes more complicated when you want to average values across multiple user input sessions as you will need persistent data in which case I would look into using Pickle or a database. Anther option would be to take multiple user inputs in the one session.

```
prospects = ['prospect1', 'prospect2', 'prospect3', 'prospect4', 'prospect5']

grades = {'A+':98, 'A':95, 'A-':92, 'B+':88, 'B':85, 'B-':82, 'C+':78, 'C':75}

out = {}

for prospect in prospects:
    rating = raw_input('Rate prospect {0}'.format(prospect))
    out[prospect] = grades[rating]

print out
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, if you want to change the average every time there is a new input, you need to store how many ratings there are. If an A+ prospect receives an F rating, their new rating will be very different if they have 1 A+ rating or 300.

You've got two options for storage, as far as I can tell. One is to use a list of tuples, where each looks like `(prospect name, total rating, number of ratings)`. The advantage of this is that you can sort it by rating very easily. The disadvantage is that looking up a specific player is harder. The other option is a dictionary, where each key is a prospect, and each value is a tuple of `(total rating, number of ratings)`. Advantages: looking up a specific player is easy. Disadvantages: sorting doesn't really make sense.

Lastly, in either case, I'd store the current rating as a number, not a letter. This would make it more accurate when averaging. Step 4 on your list should be done as a 'cosmetic' step; not modifying the prospect data. I can post example functions of you'd like, but I'm on a phone right now, so if I don't have to, I won't.

Comment: Thank you for the recommendation. Let's take out step 4 to simplify the process for now (re-converting number back to letter grades). The reason for the conversions in the first place is that prospects are usually graded in letter form, with C being the lowest grade (anything lower would not be considered a worthwhile prospect). 

My first impression is that the list of tuples would serve the purpose better. Do you mind posting a sample code of this?

Comment: Time limit on edits? Today I learned, I suppose. Anyways, pastebin link: http://pastebin.com/EPq3m68D